# copy paste from a file to another file in python webdriver

Tags: python, webdriver

Currently i am working on creating a template, my requirement is I should copy contents from a text document and paste it in the template which i am creating.
 I want to know a method in *python webdriver* to do so, i searched in the web but ended up without finding a solution, i found a similar issue Copy odt file to clipboard and paste to another file with python 3.2> here  but no solutions, any help will be grateful to me as i spent more time on this particular task.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not much to do with the webdriver, but more to do with python. As in, how do you read an ODT file using Python? That is the core of what you are doing, so webdriver is not related to the question.

With that said, there is a standard library for this, so give it a go, this can interact with all MS Office and Open Office files:

https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx

There is also a COM-based library here that can interact with Word & Excel:

http://python.net/crew/pirx/spam7/

If it's OpenOffice based files, there is the ability to automate Open Office itself for whatever you are trying to do:

http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Python

It depends on what type of text document (you only specified it was a 'text document') - if it is a simple .txt document this is very simple and easy.

Comment: Yeah that sounds great and thanks, the issue I am facing is that we have to copy a part of the text document(Yes it is just a .txt doc) and not entire file :)

Comment: Thanks @Arran, I could successfully able to solve this one all credits to you :)